# Type casting, c language problem

Tags: c, casting

I'm not able to understand some typecasting syntaxes. For eg.

```
float f=7.0;
short s=*(short *)&f;
```

What's happening here `short s=*(short *)&f`? Looks like we're casting `something` as a pointer to a short and then initializing `s` to value stored in the address pointed to by `something`.

Now, this `something` looks like the address of variable `f`. So if `something` = `address of f`, it appears to me that we are making `address of f` as a pointer to some short and then de-referencing it. I know that what I've stated is wrong, but I just can't seem to visualize it.

Thanks.

Comment: Someone answered this question but then for some reason deleted it. One point he stated was that `&f` is a pointer to a float. I guess the problem I was facing is that I would visualize `&f` as a value i.e an address and not as a variable/pointer.

So what's happening here is that a 'pointer to float' is casted as a 'pointer to short', right?

Comment: @naruto-uzumaki Yes, the cast in your example is a pointer conversion from "pointer to float" to "pointer to short".

Comment: Thanks! It feels great to learn something new everytime I post at stackoverflow :)

Comment: @naruto-uzumaki: You're right that `&f` is an address, and not a variable.  However, in C, everything has a well-defined type, not just variables.  Here, the type of `&f` is `float  *`, i.e. "pointer-to-float".

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth If I say that `&f` is a pointer to a float, is it correct?
When I posted `&f` is a variable/pointer, I basically meant that `&f` is a pointer ( Since a pointer is nothing but a 'variable' that stores an address, I sometimes refer to a pointer as a variable for my own clarity. I should proably let go of this habit :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax would make the most sense if `short` was the same size as `float` and even so, there would remain a problem with "[strict aliasing rules](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/800137-dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules)".

It is used to interpret the bits of the `float` f as representing an integer. It is used to circumvent the fact that `s = (short) f;` would be interpreted as a **conversion** to integer. Truncation, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct.  It's essentially forcing the compiler to treat the memory storing `f` as if it were actually treating a `short`.  The result of this will be platform-dependent.  This is very different to `short s = (short)f;`, which will just perform a nice conversion, and is well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

1.whenever you type cast something ,it will must in the inside of brackets( ).
2.The inside of primitive types is not higher range (size) that of other primitive types(outside of brackets).
3.After type casting the variable it will be stored in the same primitive type of which you would convert.
4.Pointer means it stores the memory of address.it will indicate the star in c.(*)

Answer (score 0):

It shoud be:

```
float f=7.0; 
short s=*(short)&f;
```

i.e the short is assigned a value 7